# How to build a SQL query from a json in react?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, reactjs

I have a requirement to modify a JSON to a JSON having the values in a SQL query format. To better explain.

```
{
 "CASE_0": {"fact_dark":"CHC_Fill"},
 "CASE_2": {"Itc_sun":"SEA_Ont"}
}
```

The result should be having the json values as an sql query leaving the keys as it is. So the resulting query will be:

```
{
CASE_0: "fact_dark = 'CHC_Fill'", 
CASE_2: "Itc_sun = 'SEA_Ont'"
}
```

I could've proceeded with regex but I couldn't figure it out well. Any elegant ES6 based solution to this?. Please folks help me out on this. TIA

Comment: You could do it manually or use a query builder like `knex.js` (if building queries from js objects is a common problem in your app)

Comment: No idea on knex.js but  how to do it manually? will it be messy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using ES6 `reduce` and `entries` method, string templates, array destructuring and spread operator:

```js
const input = {
 "CASE_0": {"fact_dark":"CHC_Fill"},
 "CASE_2": {"Itc_sun":"SEA_Ont"}
}

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((result, [CASE, caseValue]) => {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(caseValue)
  return {...result, [CASE]: `${key} = '${value}'`}
}, {})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Great solution.... but what if the value for "CASE_0" is {}?

Comment: We dont know the expected ouput in that case, could you add it to the question?

Comment: The output would be just {}

Comment: Can't understand. If filled, you get a string. If no value, you get an object? I would suggest to add the case explicitly in the question

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to transform the object into the array, for this, we use the [`Object.entries();`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Then we go through the array and create a new array using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and inside [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we create an object.

Then in the `console.log();` we deployment the array using [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator and get our object.

```js
const data = {
  "CASE_0": {"fact_dark":"CHC_Fill"},
  "CASE_2": {"Itc_sun":"SEA_Ont"}
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(n => {
  return {
    [n[0]]: `${Object.keys(n[1])} = '${Object.values(n[1])}'`,
  };
});

console.log(Object.assign(...result));
```

Comment: This accepted answer doesnt fit the expected output of the question... Returns an array of objects instead of one object